# Looking for folders in multiple extension and multiple string format

Tags: c#, getfiles

Hi I am trying to get all the files with a set of extension and a set of string format

```
string extensions=".exe,.txt,.xls";
string fileFormat"fileA, fileB, fileC";
```

let says if i have the following files in the folder

```
fileA20200805.txt
fileBxxxx.exe
FileCCCCCCC.txt
FileD123.xls
```

the result should only return the first 3 files which is

```
fileA20200805.txt
fileBxxxx.exe
FileCCCCCCC.txt
```

because FileD123.xls is not in the fileFormat.

I have tried the following code:

```
Directoryinfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = dInfoGetFiles()
.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()) && fileFormat.Any(f.Name.Contains))
.ToArray();
```

However, I am still getting all 4 files, the FileD123.xls is still returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
string[] extensions = new string[] { ".exe",".txt",".xls" };
string[] fileFormat = new string[] { "fileA", "fileB", "fileC" };
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = dInfo.GetFiles();
var output = files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()) && 
fileFormat.Any(f.Name.Contains)).ToArray();
```

it return 2 because FileCCCCCCC dont equals fileC.

Comment: my fileFormat is reading from a config, and it is just a string, is there any way to fix that? or convert that string into a string away first?

Comment: If you mean replacing a string with an array of strings then you can use Regex.  string[] output = Regex.Split(fileFormat, ",");

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
var extensions = new [] {".exe",".txt",".xls"};
var fileFormat = new [] {"fileA", "fileB", "fileC"};


...


.Where(f => 
    extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()) && 
    fileFormat.Any(x => f.Name.StartsWith(x,  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```

You could also use regex i guess

```
var regex = new Regex(@$"({string.Join("|", fileFormat)}[^.]*({string.Join(" | ", extensions)})", RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

...

.Where(f => regex.IsMatch(f.Name))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. hum the x after StartsWith is not working, it says can't convert from char to string

Comment: @kownowl i'm guessing because you didn't use the arrays