# C# - Visiting only specific files in a directory

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file

I use this function to traverse all files in a directory and executing a code for each file only if it has a specific extension, like .txt in the example. I also exclude the ones ending with .png.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDir).Where(
                f => (f.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt")) //Include
                     && !(f.ToLower().EndsWith(".png")) //Exclude
                        ).ToList())
                {
                //Do something
                }
```

This code works fine, but what if I have to deal with **several** extensions?

I would whitelisting/blacklisting every extension writing the **same** line of code over and over again.

I'm sure a clever way exists.
An idea is to store all the wanted and unwanted extension in an array.

How the code above could be improve in order to do this?

Comment: Create a collection of whitelist or blacklisted extetnsion strings outside the loop. Use `System.IO.Path.GetExtension` on the file name to get the extension in combination with Contains on the collection. I hope that will give you enough information so that you can construct a solution on your own.

Comment: if `f.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt")` is true - you don't need to check for `f.ToLower().EndsWith(".png")` (it will always be false)

Comment: also, all your code may be replaced with `foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDir, "*.txt")) { /* Do something */ }`

Comment: You should only need to check for files that you want to include, anything else will automatically be excluded. There's an example here from an earlier question today that may help with multiple extensions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262750/looking-for-folders-in-multiple-extension-and-multiple-string-format

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to have a whitelist and a blacklist at the same time. It's like saying that you "include boys, but not girls" - it's redundant. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: [Directory.EnumerateFiles method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1) has several overloads. One of them is using pattern to return files with specific name.

Comment: @vasily.sib According to the MSDN documentation doing a filter on 'xls' will also return 'xlsx'. Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_

Comment: This might be helpful too: [How to filter Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var whiteList = new List<string>{".txt"};
var blackList = new List<string>{".png"};

foreach (string file in 
            Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(rootDir)
            .Where(
                f => whiteList.Any(ext => (f.ToLower().EndsWith(ext))  //Either use a white list
                //f => !(blackList.Any(ext => (f.ToLower().EndsWith(ext))) //Or use a black list
            ).ToList())
```

Comment: While this will work, it makes no sense to simultaneously have a whitelist AND a blacklist. This should be two separate methods if anything, one for a whitelist and one for a blacklist. (If a file doesn't match an extent in the whitelist, it will fail the whitelist check and will therefore never be compared with the blacklist.)

Comment: You're correct, the whiteList part alone is enough. You can either have a white-list with items you want or a black-list with items you don't want, both won't work.